# Ckeditor upload tab missing for admins and authenticated users

Tags: 7, wysiwyg, media

I'm running a D7 system where I'm using Ckeditor, Ckeditor media and media.
I'm having an issue where within 'image' tab the 'upload' tab is only showing for superuser not for admins or rest of the users.

Admins/Authenticated 
[image]

Superadmin

[image]

Can someone please help figuring out to whats going wrong

Comment: Have you checked the issue queue for Media module? And what are your permissions for media and file entity types set at?

Comment: people >> permissions, check that.

Comment: @j.Reynolds I've checked all the permissions related to media and file entities and they are all in place.

Comment: what image browser are you using? ckFinder? imce?